# Const and weak attribute with c++ code

Tags: c++, c

I am not able to understand the compilation errors below.

First file is a header, `test_weak.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST_WEAK_H
#define TEST_WEAK_H
    #ifndef __ASSEMBLER__
const char* const TUTU __attribute__((weak)) ="TUTU";
const char* TUTU_DATE __attribute__((weak)) = __DATE__;
const char* const tutu ="tutu";
    #endif /*ASSEMBLER*/
#endif /*TEST_WEAK_H*/
```

Second file is the main `test.cpp`:

```
int main ()
{
  return 42;
}
```

To compile I run: `g++ -include test_weak.h test.cpp -o test`

Compilation result is :

```
 In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
./test_weak.h:5:44: error: weak declaration of ‘TUTU’ must be public
```

I am able to run successfully this code by replacing cpp extension by c extension on test source file and using gcc instead of g++. I am also able to fix this error by removing the weak attribute or removing the second const. So yeah I am able to fix the compilation error but no to able to understand the reason of the problem here.

For example this line compile without trouble:

```
const char* TUTU __attribute__((weak)) ="TUTU";
```

Why I cannot use a `const char* const` + weak attribute with c++ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `weak` attribute tells the linker how to handle multiple
definitions of the same entity in different translation units.
In C++, for it to be relevant, the entity must have external
linkage—that's what the linker means by "public".  In C++,
a variable which is itself `const` has internal linkage by
default.  What you probably want is:

```
extern char const* const TUTU __attribute__((weak)) = "TUTU";
```

Formally, this would be undefined behavior in C++ (without the
`__attribute__`, which isn't C++).  The purpose of the weak
attribute is to allow it, with all instances sharing the same
memory (and it *will* result in undefined behavior, or at least
unspecified, if any of the instances have a different
initializer.

Actually: what you probably want is:

```
extern char const TUTU[] __attribute__((weak)) = "TUTU";
```

No point in introducing the pointer for nothing.

EDIT:

Note that this is one of the differences between C and C++.  In
C, the `const` has no impact on linkage.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, a variable which is declared `const` and not explicitly declared `extern` receives internal linkage (that is, as if it was declared `static`). Apparently this cannot be combined with the `weak` attribute.

C doesn't have this rule, so the symbol gets external linkage and thus the attribute can be applied to it when you compile this as C code.

Comment: Note: `char TUTU[] __attribute__((weak)) ="TUTU";` compiles without issue, in line to this answer.